# Replace by centroid always decreases convex-hull volume?

Tags: convex-analysis, analytic-geometry

Let $S=\{P_i\}$ be a set of $k$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $C(S) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be their convex hull. Let $Q$ be the centroid of the points $P_i$, and let $S'$ be the set of $k$ points obtained by replacing an arbitrary point in $S$ with $Q$.

1. If $C(S)$ is open and the point replaced is a boundary point of $C(S)$, prove that $\mathrm{vol}(C(S')) < \mathrm{vol}(C(S))$, unless $S$ was degenerate with $\mathrm{vol}(C(S)) = 0$.
2. Is there a constant $0 < \gamma < 1$ (possibly depending on $k,n$), such that $\mathrm{vol}(C(S')) < \gamma \times\mathrm{vol}(C(S))$, under the same conditions as above.

Comment: Number $1$ is not true. Take $n = 1$ and $S = \{0,1,3,4\}$. If you replace $1$ or $3$ by $Q = 2$, you will not change the volume.

Comment: @gerw True. Added some additional conditions.

Comment: It is still flawed, $C(S)$ is never open.